# We have a love-hate relationship

Tags: riddle, word

> I have an arm but not a leg.
>   I like fruits but I don't eat healthy.
>   I can spin but I can't jump.

What am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are

> a [slot machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_machine) for gambling electronic games.

*I have an arm but not a leg.*

> One colloquial term for these machines is "one-armed bandits".

*I like fruits but I don't eat healthy.*

> Another is "fruit machines".

*I can spin but I can't jump.*

> They often have spinning reels.

The title might refer to the fact that

> many people love playing on these machines but hate the inevitable loss of money that results.

Comment: Wow that was fast!

Comment: @pirate I got it at once as well, only to discover that an answer had been given :/ the idea of 'one-armed bandit' was the giveaway.

Answer (score 1):

*Trying something different.*

You are a

> Business subsidiary / division

I have an arm but not a leg.

> *Google definition of arm:* a branch or division of a company or organization.

I like fruits but I don't eat healthy.

> A division that makes fruit flavored chocolates (*not healthy*)

I can spin but I can't jump.

> Spin-offs are divisions of companies or organizations that then become independent businesses with assets, employees, intellectual property, technology, or existing products that are taken from the parent company. Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_spin-off

Comment: But they can have different "legs", in the same way they have different "arms". Also the fruit clue makes no sense.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft   googling company leg does not provide any results to what you said ... https://www.google.com/search?q=company%20leg

Comment: The same is true of googling "company arm"... but both are valid usages. Check definition 7 [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leg)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft  .. no.7 says: a branch or part of an object or system ... no mention of a company

Comment: wow , downvote? without any proper justification